# problem hidding the label in chartjs (ng2chart for angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

i wanna hide the labels in the x axe on my charts, for hat i need to set the tick display:false, but when i do that, the 0 line disapear too.
i need to set the labels for make appear it in the tooltip title.
i think in just set the color of labels to transparent, but i dont think its gonna be the best way xD

[image]

```
public optionsbar: (ChartOptions) ={

responsive: false,

tooltips:{
titleFontSize:0,
bodyFontSize:10,
bodySpacing:50
},

  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        display: false,
  },
  gridLines: {
    color: '#949494',
    drawTicks: false,
    display:true,
    zeroLineColor: '#949494',
    drawBorder:true
  }
}],
xAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    beginAtZero:true,
    display: false,
    },
   gridLines: {
    color: '#949494',
    drawTicks: false,
    display:true,
    zeroLineColor: '#949494',
    drawBorder:true
   }
  }]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me and it should work as expected. It seems that the base line is drawn but it doesn't fit inside the `canvas`.

This problem can be solved by replacing `xAxis.gridlines.drawTicks: false` by `xAxis.gridlines.tickMarkLength: 1` as shown below.

```
xAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    display: false,
  },
  gridLines: {
    color: '#949494',
    // drawTicks: false,
    tickMarkLength: 1,
    zeroLineColor: '#949494',
  }
}]
```

Another option would be to define some [`padding`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html#padding) at the bottom of the chart as follows:

```
options: {
  layout: {
    padding: {
      bottom: 1
    }
  },
  ...
```